# Indicator function, problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is this correct:

Let $ S = [1, 2, 3], X = I_{{1}}, Y = I_{{2,3}}, Z = I_{{1,2}}. $ Let $ W = X - Y + Z. $ ($ I_A $ is the indicator function of A.)
Compute $W(1), W(2)$ and $W(3).$

$W(1) = 1 - 0 + 1 = 2$,
$W(2) = 0 - 1 + 1 = 0$,
$W(3) = 0 - 1 + 0 = -1$

?

My text book doesn't agree with me and gives the solutions $ W(1) = 1$ and $W(3) = 0.$

Comment: Your answers look right. Do you have a link to the problem statement?

Comment: No, I don't have a link, sorry, but I quoted it exactly so there is no other information given anyway. I think my answer looks right too and I'm thinking it might just be an error in the book.